# Автоматическая установка mySQL 5.7.18 type and networking нет кнопки

Tags: mysql, установка

Привет! Доходит до этого этапа установки, а кнопки, чтобы продолжить нет!

[image: Пробовал ранние версии,]

там все останавливается на "starting server".

Answer (score 2):

Это известный баг. Он описан [тут](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85973).

Решение: нажмите сочетание клавиш `alt+N` - переход Next. Если оно запросит `Apply configuration` и не будет кнопки execute, то применяете `alt+X`.

**UPD.** Некоторым помогало изменение размера шрифта Windows. По умолчанию он стоит 100%, но если вы его меняли (например, на 125%), то нужно его уменьшить до 100% и кнопка появится.